# Proper way to check for null dates in Flex/Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, date, flex3, flex4

When working with `Date()` objects in Flex/Actionscript, I'm using to following function to check for null dates. Is this the proper way to check for a null date or is there a better alternative out there?

```
public function IsDateNull(date:Date):Boolean
{
  if (date && date.fullYear != 0)
  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, since Date is a class that extends Object and isn't a primitive type it doesn't have a default value and therefore should only be null if it hasn't yet been instantiated.  Is the Date being populated from some sort of database mapping or something along those lines? otherwise not just if(!date) no need to have a function to do this.

Comment: @shaunhusain I was about to say something similar.  You should post that as a real answer.  I'd feel guilty doing it and stealing the Karma that is rightfully due to you.

Comment: @shaunhusain, The dates are coming from a variety of places: back end data calls, `DateField.selectedDate`, etc. I've run into situations where I have to set `DateField.selectableRange` based on the `selectedDate` value of another `DateField` or from the back end data. In these situations, the Date object I'd like to use could be null. That's the reason I'm using this check. I hope that makes sense. EDIT: And please do add that as an answer! I'll gladly upvote. :)

Comment: The reason I have the `fullYear` check is because when data is coming from the back end via FluorineFX, it uses a default date of 12/31/0 if not date was provided for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Date is a class that extends Object and isn't a primitive type it doesn't have a default value and therefore should only be null if it hasn't yet been instantiated. Is the Date being populated from some sort of database mapping or something along those lines? otherwise not just

```
if(!date)
```

or

```
if(date==null)
```

no need to have a function to do this.  For the DateField.selectedDate the value should be null if no date has been selected yet.  This wasn't originally posted as an answer because I don't entirely understand the issue being encountered it sounds as though there's a variety of cases though.  Depending on the service layer and underlying JDBC (or other connector) to the DB and the type of DB and datatype the values can vary.  In general a Date will be null until memory is acquired for it through a call to the constructor though.

Thanks,
Shaun