# FlexBuilder dateField '01/01/1901'

Tags: apache-flex

I've a dateField in FlexBuilder that returns DateTime from WebService C# and SqlServer.
The dateField show all DateTime from SqlServer, but with Date 'Null', It shows '01/01/1901'

What I need to do to get the datetime instead of null in date field.

Comment: You can refer to this for putting a check on null date values-


  [proper-way-to-check-for-null-dates-in-flex-actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171646/proper-way-to-check-for-null-dates-in-flex-actionscript)

Comment: That's what you want to do specifically, can you explain a little more detailed. Since you have many options, depending on what you want to do or show. Regars

Comment: PERFECT!!! I modified code:

Comment: public function IsDateNull(date:Date):Date
   {
    if (date && date.fullYear == 1901)
    {
     return null;
    }
    else
    {
     dateTimeFormatter1.format(date);
     return date;
    } 
   }

Comment: PERFECT!!! I modified code: public function IsDateNull(date:Date):Date { if (date && date.fullYear == 1901) { return null; } else { dateTimeFormatter1.format(date); return date; } }  but now i've new proble...but now in I can't use labelfunction for formatter!!!!  <mx:DateField id="sData_ComunicazioneOSDateField"
        selectedDate="{classeDati.sData_ComunicazioneOS}" labelFunction="IsDateNull" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this case on database layer so that all clients of this stored procedure / query will get same default value in case of null.

here's an example:

```
SELECT name, ISNULL (dateofbirth,  GETDATE() ) FROM user
```

GETDATE() will return today's (server's system) date instead.

of-course not a reasonable default in above example, and you might want to do date manipulations for calculating some default value. you can use [these reference docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem :

```
public function IsDateNull(date:Date):String`enter code here`enter code here
{



if (date && date.fullYear == 1901)
        {
        return null;
        }
        else
        {
        return dateTimeFormatter1.format(date);
        }
```

}

```
<s:DateTimeFormatter id="dateTimeFormatter1"                             
dateTimePattern="EEEE, dd MMMM , yyyy "
dateStyle="long" locale="it-IT"
errorText="Invalid input value"
useUTC="false"/> 

<mx:DateField id="sData_ComunicazioneOSDateField" selectedDate="{classeDati.sData_ComunicazioneOS}" labelFunction="IsDateNull" />
```

Thank you for the help!!!